# I want to perform a certain command over SSH and it's not working, but other commands are. How come?

Tags: python, ssh, command-line-interface

I am trying to perform a command over SSH.  The setup is I have my code on my remote laptop (machine 1), and I want to SSH into a linux machine (machine 2) to perform a command which compiles all of the data in machine 2 into a csv file.

My code looks like this:

```
import subprocess

ipaddress = "123.45.678.90"
cmd1 = """mysql --batch -u redacted -p"redacted" -h 789.01.234.567 -D redacted -e " SELECT redacted WHERE redacted > '2020-04-13 10:39:42' AND redacted < '2020-04-13 12:46:27' AND redacted AND redacted AND redacted;" > file_name.csv"""
cmd2 = "touch test.txt"
subprocess.Popen("ssh {ip} {cmd}".format(ip=ipaddress, cmd=cmd2), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

In the above code, when I use cmd2 to test with, I'm able to run the code, then manually SSH into machine 2 on machine 1's CLI and see that the file "test.txt" was created on machine 2.

However if I use cmd1 in the above code, then I manually SSH into machine 2, I don't see the file I want created.  I can SSH into machine 2 and manually copy/paste the contents of cmd2 in and it works.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is?  Thanks!

*Edit* I added an err, out to the subprocess.popopen command and when using cmd1, the print(err) message is:

```
b"bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('\nbash: -c: line 0: `mysql --batch -u redacted -predacted -h 789.01.234.567 -D redacted -e  SELECT redacted WHERE redacted > '2020-04-13 10:39:42' AND redacted < '2020-04-13 12:46:27' AND redacted AND redacted AND redacted;'\n"
```

It looks like in the error printout, the command was stripped of all of its double quotes, as well as the final `" > file_name.csv` was stripped, which is what tells the command where to save the file.  Here's a side by side comparison of the original command that is supposed to be sent, and what the err msg gave back:

```
origi: mysql --batch -u redacted -p"redacted" -h 789.01.234.567 -D redacted -e " SELECT redacted WHERE redacted > '2020-04-13 10:39:42' AND redacted < '2020-04-13 12:46:27' AND redacted AND redacted AND redacted;" > file_name.csv
error: mysql --batch -u redacted -predacted -h 789.01.234.567 -D redacted -e  SELECT redacted WHERE redacted > '2020-04-13 10:39:42' AND redacted < '2020-04-13 12:46:27' AND redacted AND redacted AND redacted;'\n"
```

How do I make sure my original command gets passed into the subprocess.Popen function?  It looks like all of the double quotes got stripped.  If I do a simple print(cmd1), it prints out my command like normal.  Thanks

Comment: Try to `out, err = subprocess.Popen...(rest of command)` and then `print(err)` to see if you get an error.

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried that and there was indeed an error, but I'm not sure what it means.  I'll update hte main post with the error.

Answer (score -1):

Every pair of quotes of the same type, Python is interpreting that as a separate string. It looks like you are trying to bind cmd1 to a bunch of different strings.

Instead of:

```
cmd1 = """mysql --batch -u redacted -p"redacted" -h redacted -D testexec -e " SELECT redacted(over 30 parameters)"
```

Try this:

```
cmd1 = '""mysql --batch -u redacted -p"redacted" -h redacted -D testexec -e " SELECT redacted(over 30 parameters)" > file_name.csv""'
```

Comment: I tried that and it's giving me the following error
```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When i did tried what you recommended with the single quotes, a lot of the strings inside turned from green to white or orange or other colors.